# Check string for all letters in another string without repeating C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to check a word against another word (original word) if it has all the letters from the original word without repeating any. E.g

Case 1 :

- original word = someword
- word to check = door
- result : correct, all letters found in original word.
- Score : 4 (out of 4)

Case 2 :

- original word = someword
- word to check = wordeee
- result: incorrect, repeated e more than found in original word.
- Score : 5 (out of 7)

Hope this helps, so far:

```
foreach (var c in _word)
{
    if (_starting_string.Contains(c))
    {
        score++;
    }
    else
        return null;             
    }
}
```

I need to increment `score` for every letter in the `_word` if the `_starting_string` contains the letter but without it being repeated/used already. Any solutions?

Kind regards.

Comment: so what's the question here? Any?

Comment: Either remove characters as found and repeat (recursion may be fun here), or store characters and counts in a data structure of some kind.

Comment: looks like doing someone's homework….

Comment: @FalcoAlexander - Helping with homework does not need to be an issue as long as sufficient effort has been shown (whether that has been met here or not is open to your interpretation).

Comment: Count how many time `c` appears in `_word`. Count how many times `c` appears in `_starting_string`. Compare.

Comment: The question: "Any solutions?": Yes. Use a Dictionary<char, int> to count the chars in the orignal word, than decrement for each char in the second word.

Comment: You should always provide, an example input, example expected output. What you have already tried, and a clear indicator of what any potential error messages are. 

Technically stackoverflow is not a code writing service. Sometimes people provide their solutions in this way, but you need to reword your question if you don't want massive downvotes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
string startingWord = "someword";
string checkWord = "door";

List<char> list = startingWord.ToList();

int score = 0;

for (int i = 0; i < checkWord.Length; i++)
{
    if (list.Any(c => c == checkWord[i])
    {
        score++;
        list.RemoveAt(list.FirstIndex(c => c == checkWord[I]));
    }
}

bool match = score == checkWord.Length;
```

Comment: `foreach (char c in word)
                {
                    if (_startingstring_list.Contains(c))
                    {
                        score++;
                        _startingstring_list.Remove(c);

                    }
                    else
                        return null;
                }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply build two dictionaries holding the characters as key and the number of occurrences as values?

```
var map1 = _startingString.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x);
var map2 = _word.GroupBy(x => x).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x);
```

Finally compare the counts for every character in your dictionary:

```
foreach(var kv in map1)
{
    if(map2.ContainsKey(kv.Key) && map2[kv.Key].Count() !=  map1[kv.Key].Count)
        throw new Exception(...);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This seems to have worked, Thank you.

```
List<char> _startingstring_list = startingstring.ToList();
foreach (char c in word)
            {
                if (_startingstring_list.Contains(c))
                {
                    score++;
                    _startingstring_list.Remove(c);

                }
                else
                    return null;
            }
```